# Erlang, yecc and EBNF

Tags: erlang, yacc, lex, bnf, ebnf

I want to implement a lexer and parser in Erlang.  The Erlang docs talk about [yecc](http://erlang.org/doc/man/yecc.html) and [leex](http://erlang.org/doc/man/leex.html) which should be incredibly helpful.  However, the yecc doc only mentions support for BNF grammar notation, not [EBNF](http://www.garshol.priv.no/download/text/bnf.html#id2.3.).

I'd like to use EBNF if I can help it though I can't find any documentation as to whether Erlang's yecc support EBNF.  Does it?

Comment: The yecc documentation you reference appears to include the grammar for yecc files itself, and that grammar does not include anything which would handle EBNF descriptions. So unless the documentation is  dramatically outdated, it seems to clearly indicate that the answer is "No". (If I had an erlang installation, I might venture an answer rather than a comment.)

Answer (score 2):

The [yecc documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/yecc.html) mentions only BNF and does not use EBNF in its examples, and as far as I can see there are no yecc source files in the [OTP source tree](https://github.com/erlang/otp) that utilize EBNF, so I think it's safe to say that yecc supports BNF only.